# How the JmsConfiguration can now be set to EmbeddedActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-artemis

`EmbeddedJMS` is deprecated in favor of `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.embedded.EmbeddedActiveMQ`.
With `EmbeddedJMS` you can set a `JMSConfiguration`.

```java
Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationImpl();
...
JMSConfiguration jmsConfig = new JMSConfigurationImpl();
...
EmbeddedJMS jmsServer = new EmbeddedJMS().setConfiguration(configuration).setJmsConfiguration(jmsConfig).start();
```

How the `JmsConfiguration` can now be set to `EmbeddedActiveMQ`?

Answer (score 0):

Server-side configuration should be expressed exclusively in terms of "core" resources (i.e. addresses, queues, & routing-types). See [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/jms-core-mapping.html) for details on how JMS queues and JMS topics map to core resources.

Also, there should be no need to configure any JNDI related details from `JMQConfiguration` anymore since JNDI look-ups are now handled by a client-side only implementation. See [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/using-jms.html) for more details on that as well.

To be clear, JMS-specific configuration elements (both programmatic and XML) were deprecated after the scope of ActiveMQ Artemis was broadened by adding support for STOMP, AMQP, & MQTT. Like JMS, each of these protocols has its own quirks and conventions. However, we didn't want to add specific XML elements and APIs to support each protocol, and ultimately it no longer made sense to have the same for JMS either.